# Align left and align right across lines

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I am new to latex and I want the following format but simple things like `\hfill` does not help here.

```
Name:XX                                                          Email: abc@example.com
Work:YY                                                          Phone: +1 666222
```

In particular I want starting of `phone` and `email` to be aligned, as well as Name and Work to be aligned.

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{}}
Name& zz\\
Work& zzz
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rr@{}}
email& z\\
phone& zzz
\end{tabular}
```

You need to align each side in a box (eg tabular) then push them apart with `\hfill`

Comment: Could you please explain this : `@{}ll@{}`

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam `ll` is two left aligned columns `@{}` removes the cell padding (`\tabcolsep`) that would normally be around the table

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam You may want `ll` in the right hand table as well rather than `rr` depending on the style you want.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, David Carlisle's answer works great. But, in general if you want table to span the entire `\linewidth`, I find using the `X` column from `tabularx` to be very useful:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.
  was just to show the page margins.
- Here I have used the `X` column to be the blank column between the two groups of text. Hence the double `&&` separating the two groups.
- The `@{}` at the left and right of the table remove the inter column padding that would normally be applied.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l l X l l@{}}
    Name: & XX   && Email: & abc@example.com\\
    Work: & YYY  && Phone: & +1 666222\\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{document}
```